# ASp.net pass formula field value to crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, report, field, formula

i am new to crystal report. I now facing a problem. How can i pass multiple formula field to my crystal report? 
Here is my coding

```
   private void ConfigureCrystalReports()
    {
        ReportDocument  RepDoc = new ReportDocument();

        nsFilterData.Report report = (nsFilterData.Report)Session["report"];
        RepDoc.Load(Server.MapPath(report.reportPath));

        CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = report.selectForumula;
        RepDoc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["test1"].Text = "2";
        RepDoc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["test2"].Text = "abc";
         CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RepDoc;

    }
```

In my crystal report , i got two formula field which name "test1" and "test2". How do i pass the value to crystal report? Thanks you

Comment: Do you want to generate the formula on run-time and then pass to crystal report ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass values to your Crystal Report, use Parameters, and then use those parameters values in formula fields...

If you get me your requirements clearly, I can help u more on this !